# PowerShell command to create a directory on a remote machine

Tags: java, powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a PowerShell command to create a directory on a remote machine... But it throws an expection.

```
Command
New-Item \\<remotemachine>\C$\Users\Public\tmpApp.userID.Domain -ItemType Directory


Exception

Caused by: com.windows.ExecuteException:  Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Through Powershell
New-Item : Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Logon failure is just that, the account that launched the command does not have permission to get either `c$` on the remote machine or write to the destination folder. /thread

Answer (score 0):

Try this using remoting.  Run this from an elevated prompt:

```
Invoke-Command <remotemachinename> {mkdir C:\users\public\tmpApp.userID.Domain}
```

You will need to enable remote on remotemachinename by running this command in an elevated PowerShell prompt:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -force
```

If you need to run the mkdir command under different credentials, tack on the parameter/argument combo `-Credential (Get-Credential)`.

Comment: this is not working `Invoke-Command <machinename> {mkdir C:\Users\Public} -Authentication Default -credential Administrator
[machinename] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : Logon failure: unknown u
ser name or bad password. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.`

Comment: You are not using the credential parameter correctly.  First try the interactive prompt e.g. `-Credential (Get-Credential)` to see if that works.

Comment: My first question, i am firing this command in Java, So when i try to fire the`Enable-PSRemoting` , it gives exception as `Enable-PSRemoting : Access is denied. You need to run this cmdlet from an elevated process.`...

Comment: How to run this command in elevated mode. In powershell , we can use Run As Administrator and continue, but while doing in java i have a process and it executes the command. This gives me exception as shown above. How to achieve this is java code. I am posting command also for reference